# Python проблема с путями

Tags: python

Работаю на windows10. 
Есть две папки одна лежит в другой, скрипт питона во второй папке (которая вложенная). Визуально в проводнике windows это видно, при выполнении скрипта:

```
print(os.getcwd())
```

Выводит C:\test_py 
По факту так - C:\test_py\test1 
Тоесть сам питон не видит то что он находится во вложенной папке. При выполнении:

```
print(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))
```

Папку видит, и выводит её

Подскажите как решить данную проблему

Comment: getcwd показывает не папку скрипта, а текущую рабочую папку. Куда вы сделаете `cd` в командной строке, та папка и будет показываться

Comment: Что тут решать? О какой проблеме речь?

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pathlib import Path

d = Path(__file__)
print(d.as_posix())
```